# Neovim only underline LSP diagnostics that are part of a line

Tags: neovim, lsp

I only want an LSP diagnostic to have an underline if the underline covers only part of the non-whitespace text of a line. I have a column of diagnostic signs so a full line being underlined gives no information and is visual clutter. However, I like when only part of a line is underlined since this tells me where in the line the issue is.

This seems like it should be possible using either

```lua
vim.diagnostic.config({
  underline = function(namespace, bufnr)
    ???
  end
})
```

or

```lua
vim.lsp.handlers["textDocument/publishDiagnostics"] = vim.lsp.with(
  vim.lsp.diagnostic.on_publish_diagnostics, { ??? }
)
```

but I can't work it out.

Thanks